# In python, how can I make a dict/typeddict that has a default type and type hints for known keys (additionalProperties implementation)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, types

In python, how can I make a dict that has type hints for know keys and a default type for unknown keys?

I have tried using a typing.TypeDict but I do not see how to set the type on the unknown key type.

```
import typing
class SomeDict(typing.Typeddict):
    a: str
    b: int

some_dict = SomeDict({"a": "a", "b": 0, "c": 3.14})
val_a = some_dict.get("a")
val_b = some_dict.get("b")
val_c = some_dict.get("c")
```

This would be especially helpful if an IDE like pycharm or vscode could correctly see the type of the value stored in the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible today in visual studio code (vscode).
See the below working example.

```
import typing

class SomeDict(dict):

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, name: typing.Literal["a"]) -> str: ...

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, name: typing.Literal["b"]) -> int: ...

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, name: str) -> float: ...

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return super().__getitem__(name)

...

some_dict = SomeDict({"a": "a", "b": 0, "hi there": 1.234})
val_a = some_dict["a"]  # str
val_b = some_dict["b"]  # bool
another_val = some_dict["hi there"]  # float
```

Validating those inputs is left up to the developer
One could implement that in `__new__` or `__init__`.
Hopefully pycharm will support this soon in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42137/PyCharm-type-hinting-doesnt-work-well-with-overload-decorator

And with the soon to be added [python 3.11 PEP 675 addition of typing.LiteralString](https://peps.python.org/pep-0675/) one could

- require that only string literals are passed in, and that generic strings are not passed in (if one wanted)
- or set the type hint on str to include all of the overloaded types because that would happen when a non-literal string is passed in

But this is only for retrieval of properties, it is not for assigning properties to the dict :(

### Update:

- per mypy, literals also match string so one cannot use str to only match additional properties. One needs to write a separate get_additional_property method which will always return the additional property type.

Comment: There's a problem with this, though: if `key == "a"`, then the inferred type of `some_dict[key]` is `float`, not `str`, because `key` has type `str`, not `Literal["a"]`. `Literal` really does refer to *literals*, not just specific values.

Comment: It looks like you asking about passing in a non-literal str with the value of "a". Didn't I covered that in my points about typing.LiteralString?

Comment: A future addition doesn't make the current suggestion any less problematic.

Comment: Does the future addition that I mentioned solve for the use case that you mentioned? I think it does. Just trying to do the best that I can here. If you have an alternate solution that will work please post it. I mentioned the issue that you mentioned in the solution.